# Asp.Net. Как скрыть символы (value) под звёздочками при вводе пароля

Tags: asp.net, textbox

Не знает ли кто, есть ли прямой способ скрыть символы в атрибуте value в texbox при вводе пароля. Звёздочки конечно символы скрывают (TextMode="password") , но если проинспектировать страницу, то, добравшись до контрола, значение пароля лежит в отрытом виде в value.

Comment: Для этого я вам советую создать свой обработчик клавиатуры, перехватив например oninput, и рисовать звёздочки самому, а значение хранить в полузашифрованом виде в переменной js - тогда ваш пароль будет уязвим лишь для начинающих хакеров знающих js-дебаггер (он находится рядом на соседней вкладке с инспектором), сомневаюсь что таких мало. И дописать ASP. P.S. asp net и веб-обозреватель ведут себя нормально.

Comment: Какой смысл на клиентской стороне что-либо защищать? Любой чудесный js-скрипт можно поломать.

Comment: Ну вот именно по причине продвинутых дебаггеров в браузерах я и не хотел писать какие-то js, ибо их подсмотреть не сложнее, чем вёрстку.